# Postman shows "Could not get any response" even though response is OK

Tags: wcf, gzip, postman

I have a WCF service which I make API requests to.
This API call returns a JSON response object and also is able to return it in GZIP compression as well when "gzip" value is used in "Accept-Encoding" header.

The problem is when I try to get the response in GZIP, Postman shows "Could not get any response" although I see response and response's content are OK (200 status code) in Fiddler and can easily decompress the response content in my C# client.

I took a look in Postman Console but all I see is **"Error: incorrect header check"**.
I hardly tried to find any documentation regarding this header check but couldn't find any.

**These are the request headers:**

```
POST /correction/v1/document?lang=US HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.0
Accept: */*
content-length: 630
Connection: close
```

**These are the response headers:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 512
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Sun, 24 Feb 2019 14:05:50 GMT
Connection: close
```

The only thing I suspect is wrong is this message from Fiddler:

### [image: Fidler]

I integrated this code into mine in order to use GZIP in WCF.
https://github.com/carlosfigueira/WCFSamples/tree/master/MessageEncoder/GZipEncoderAndAutoFormatSelection

Basically, it captures the response before returning to client and use GZipStream for compression.

Answer (score 16):

I got the same issue, I added the following header to fix this issue.

```
Accept-Encoding : *
```

[image]

Comment: In my case "*" didn't work - I had to explicitly set it as "application/zip"

Comment: I wish you had explained why? And what to do to fix it from the serverside

Comment: @ErenAygunes Do you or anybody know why `application/zip` works ?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve a similar issue by using the header `Accept-Encoding: */*` or if you want to be specific do `Accept-Encoding: */*` that way the HTTP client will be able to process the response based on the type of encoding received, in the case of a gzip, it will decode the response and show it as normal text.

Answer (score 4):

For me, I removed 'Accept-Encoding' in the request header.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue when the REST service was returning a `zip` content (aka. WinZip format). I solved the error by compressing the data using 7zip to produce true `gzip` format.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when:

```
$config['compress_output'] = true;
```

Comment: In application/config/config.php

Comment: Can you cite/add a reference for this behavior?